# matplotlib argrelmax doesn't find all maxes

Tags: python, scipy, sampling

I have a project where I'm sampling analog data and attempting to analyze with matplotlib.  Currently, my analog data source is a potentiometer hooked up to a microcontroller, but that's not really relevant to the issue.  Here's my code

```
arrayFront = RunningMean(array(dataFront), 15)
arrayRear = RunningMean(array(dataRear), 15)
x = linspace(0, len(arrayFront), len(arrayFront))  # Generate x axis
y = linspace(0, len(arrayRear), len(arrayRear))  # Generate x axis
min_vals_front = scipy.signal.argrelmin(arrayFront, order=2)[0]  # Min
min_vals_rear = scipy.signal.argrelmin(arrayRear, order=2)[0]  # Min
max_vals_front = scipy.signal.argrelmax(arrayFront, order=2)[0]  # Max
max_vals_rear = scipy.signal.argrelmax(arrayRear, order=2)[0]  # Max
maxvalfront = max(arrayFront[max_vals_front])
maxvalrear = max(arrayRear[max_vals_rear])
minvalfront = min(arrayFront[min_vals_front])
minvalrear = min(arrayRear[min_vals_rear])
plot(x, arrayFront, label="Front Pressures")
plot(y, arrayRear, label="Rear Pressures")
plot(x[min_vals_front], arrayFront[min_vals_front], "x")
plot(x[max_vals_front], arrayFront[max_vals_front], "o")
plot(y[min_vals_rear], arrayRear[min_vals_rear], "x")
plot(y[max_vals_rear], arrayRear[max_vals_rear], "o")
xlim(-25, len(arrayFront) + 25)
ylim(-1000, 7000)
legend(loc='upper left')
show()
```

dataFront and dataRear are python lists that hold the sampled data from 2 potentiometers.  RunningMean is a function that calls:

```
convolve(x, ones((N,)) / N, mode='valid')
```

The problem is that the argrelmax (and min) functions don't always find all the maxes and mins.  Sometimes it doesn't find ANY max or mins, and that causes me problems in this block of code

```
maxvalfront = max(arrayFront[max_vals_front])
maxvalrear = max(arrayRear[max_vals_rear])
minvalfront = min(arrayFront[min_vals_front])
minvalrear = min(arrayRear[min_vals_rear])
```

because the [min_vals_(blank)] variables are empty.  Does anyone have any idea what is happening here, and what I can do to fix the problem?  Thanks in advance.

Here's one of graphs of data where not all the maxes and mins are found:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`signal.argrelmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelmin.html#scipy-signal-argrelmin) is a thin wrapper around [`signal.argrelextrema`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html#scipy.signal.argrelextrema) with `comparator=np.less`. `np.less(a, b)` returns the truth value of `a < b` element-wise. Notice that `np.less` requires `a` to be **strictly less than** `b` for it to be True.

[Your data](http://pastebin.com/717HNLs0) has the same minimum value at a lot of neighboring locations. At the local minima, the inequality between local minimum and its neighbors does not satisfy a *strictly less than* relationship; instead it only satisfies a **strictly less than or equal** to relationship.

Therefore, to find these extrema use `signal.argrelmin` with `comparator=np.less_equal`. For example, using a snippet from your data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

arrayRear = np.array([-624.59309896, -624.59309896, -624.59309896,
                      -625., -625., -625.,])

print(signal.argrelmin(arrayRear, order=2)[0])
# []

print(signal.argrelextrema(arrayRear, np.less_equal)[0])
# [0 1 3 4 5]

print(signal.argrelextrema(arrayRear, np.less_equal, order=2)[0])
# [0 3 4 5]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I removed the order=2 portion, but I still get the same behavior for long stretches of the same value, as in the image here.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyuwkfs42ga0swj/Cell1-2015-06-04T13%3A45%3A58.241825.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I'm not too worried about local maxes on the edge.  But when I lose the max/mins in the middle like here https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8m3iq8uhjq7tnt/Cell1-2015-06-04T14%3A10%3A21.383191.jpg?dl=0 I get worried.  In my application, it is critical that I be able to detect these points of inflection.

Comment: Well, you probably know this is coming: can you post some data which reproduces the problem?

Comment: This set of data http://pastebin.com/717HNLs0 produced no min points with argrelmin (contents of arrayRear for a single run) . The value of the variable "min_vals_rear" is "array([], dtype=int32)".  This produces an error in minvalrear = min(arrayRear[min_vals_rear]) and exits with ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: would I use argrelextrema with np.greater_equal to find local maxima?

Comment: Awesome.  This solves the problem, and detects edge min and max as well.  Thank you very much!